# Is it better to pass arrays in view or objects in MVC?

Tags: arrays, laravel, model-view-controller, dto, code-cleanup

Referring to this question: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/218391/arrays-vs-objects-in-view-template

I was wondering what are the best practices to pass data from controller to view? 
I'm currently working on php/Laravel and using service layer between controller and models. I'm not using repository layer yet, so just getting eloquent object from models and passing them to controller then view. The format is not persistent, at some location the data is being passed as eloquent object/collection and at some points it's being passed in an associative array format.

We know, the best practice is that our view should know least about the backend code/structure. If we pass an eloquent object to the view, then our view even knows the field names in models. This way, changing one model field name will break our code till the view.

If we pass array then we can definitely such kind of information? There is also some concept about DTO (Data transfer object), how it can help in hiding our data from view? I'm looking for a way through which my front-end and back-end least depend on each other.

Comment: you may convert your eloquent objects to a custom object in that way you may expose only the fields that you want to expose. One of the disadvantage of ORMs is that fields are exposed by default - you may hide them and expose only the methods. In that way if you change full_name to fullName, your api will be still valid since it will be only access full name on getFullName() -  you may also check eloquent resorces https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-resources